# Getting all attributes for stored objects in filesystem directory in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, persistence

I know of this method: `resourceValueForKeys` which given an `NSURL` and a array of keys will fetch the attribuest of the file for you... But what I need is something that enumerates 
through all files in a given `NSURL` directory and gives me the attributes.

I tried doing this with an enumerator in `NSFileSystem` class but could not get it to work, anyone know the right way to do this?... I am not using Core Data.

```
   NSDictionary *values = [fileDirectory resourceValuesForKeys:@[NSURLAttributeModificationDateKey] error:nil];
    NSLog(@"object: %@", values);
```

Comment: Stored Objects  -> file /folders in system ? ios or osx?

Comment: iOS, updated my question

Comment: Use `NSFileManager` to get the contents of a folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enumerate through all files in a given directory:

```
NSArray * arrayOfURLs = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:URL includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLIsDirectoryKey,
        NSURLNameKey,NSURLFileSizeKey,NSURLContentModificationDateKey,
        NSURLLocalizedTypeDescriptionKey]
                              options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles 
                                error:nil];

for ( NSURL file in arrayOfURLs ) {
    NSString * nameOfFile;
    [file getResourceValue:&nameOfFile forKey:NSURLNameKey error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", nameOfFile);

    ...... and so forth for the rest of values ...

}
```

this way you can get all the values for all the files contained in the folder.

Comment: This methods returns an array of `NSURL` objects pointing to the files in the folder.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/your file path"];
NSLog(@"Your path: %@",path);
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *attributesOfYourItem = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&error];
if(error)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
else
    NSLog(@"Attribute dictionary: %@",attributesOfYourItem);
```

Comment: Your code for getting a path in the Documents directory is not ideal. And please don't use string formats unless you actually have a string to format.

Comment: Thanx for your good advise.
Could you tell the ideal code for getting a path in document directory?

Comment: @maddy in the context of the answer it makes sense to use a format since in real use you'd be appending sub-directories and filenames onto the home directory path.